Proof that Natural Processes are Predictable from Kallenberg (Lemma 10.9)
A key part of proving that a natural, increasing process is predictable is to show that the jumps can only occur at predictable stopping times (i.e. showing that the jumps are $0$ almost surely at every totally inaccessible stopping time). This is the topic of the following lemma from Kallenberg, whose proof I understand precisely $0\%$ of:

My many questions and problems:
I am not sure how to rescale a process in time so that all of its (countably many) discontinuities all avoid the Dyadic rationals. Is it simply by considering the process $\widetilde A_t \equiv A_{t/\sqrt{2}}$ (if $A$ had any discontinuities at a Dyadic rational, these discontinuities are now at $\sqrt{2} k/2^n$ for the process $\widetilde A$)?
The equality $(1)$ in red is an absolute mystery to me. The definition of a natural process implies that equalities of the type $(1)$ hold when the integrand is a martingale. But $P(\tau_n > t | \mathcal{F}_t)$ is a supermartingale. I am entirely lost.
Now, even if one takes that as a given, Lemma 10.8 implies that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{t \ge 0} |P(\tau_n > t| \mathcal{F}_t) - \mathbb{1}_{\tau > t}| = 0, \quad \textbf{(L10.8)}$$
so the left hand side of $(1)$ converges to the right hand side of $(2)$. I am not sure of why this also implies the right hand side of $(1)$ converges to the first term in $(3)$. Is it because $$P(\tau_n > t | \mathcal{F}_{t-}) = \lim_{s \uparrow t} P(\tau_n > s | \mathcal{F}_s) ?  \qquad \textbf{(4)} $$
If this were true, then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}| P(\tau_n > t | \mathcal{F}_{t-}) - \mathbb{1}_{\tau \ge t}| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{s \uparrow t}| P(\tau_n > s | \mathcal{F}_{s}) - \mathbb{1}_{\tau > s}| = 0 $$ by $\textbf{(4)}$. How does one show $\textbf{(4)}$?
After all that is resolved, the conclusion follows immediately.
Thank you for any help you can give in making this more clear, and apologies for my many misunderstandings here. I have mainly resolved the issues but there is still one part I am missing/don't understand (see my partial answer below, regarding the future bounty).

I have partial resolutions to all of my issues:
To prove $(1)$, we fix a sequence of partitions of $[0, \infty)$, $\{t_k^K\}_{k = 0}^\infty$, $K \in \mathbb{N}$, with $t_k^K \equiv \frac{k}{2^K}$. Since $A$ is natural, one has
$$E\int_{(t_k^K, t_{k+1}^K]} P(\tau_n > u|\mathcal{F}_t) dA_t = E\int_{(t_k^K, t_{k+1}^K]} P(\tau_n > u|\mathcal{F}_{t-}) dA_t $$ for any $u \ge 0$. In particular, at $u = t_{k+1}^K$, so defining $$X^K(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(\tau_n > t_{k+1}^K | \mathcal{F}_t) \mathbf{1}(t \in (t_k^K, t_{k+1}^K])$$ and $$X^K_-(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P(\tau_n > t_{k+1}^K | \mathcal{F}_{t-}) \mathbf{1}(t \in (t_k^K, t_{k+1}^K]),$$
we have
$$E\int_{(0,\infty)} X^K(t) dA_t = E\int_{(0,\infty)} X^K_-(t) dA_t$$ for every $K \in \mathbb{N}$. Due to the right continuity of the simple function $f(u) = \mathbf{1}(\tau_n > u)$, we see that $X^K(t) \rightarrow P(\tau_n > t|\mathcal{F}_t)$ and $X^K_-(t) \rightarrow P(\tau_n > t|\mathcal{F}_{t-})$ so that $(1)$ follows by the dominated convergence theorem. I am particularly worried about this part, since I feel like it relies on some regular conditional probability results, and in particular we have the existence of a regular conditional probability with respect to $\mathcal{F}_t$ a.s. for each $t \ge 0$ and not for all $t \ge 0$, a.s. I am convinced there is a problem here and cannot reconcile it.

(4) is actually false, but we will rely on the fact that $A$ is continuous at the dyadic rationals to prove the right hand side of $(2)$ converges to the first term in $(3)$. First, we claim that $$\lim_{s \uparrow t} P(\tau_n > s | \mathcal{F}_s) = P(\tau_n \ge t |\mathcal{F}_{t-}).$$
Since $P(\tau_n > s | \mathcal{F}_s)$ is a supermartingale, the limit on the LHS exists almost surely. Now, if $A \in \mathcal{F}_s$ for $s < t$, then for any $u \in (s,t)$, we have $$E(\mathbf{1}_A \mathbf{1}(\tau_n > u)) = E(\mathbf{1}_A P(\tau_n > u | \mathcal{F}_u))$$ by definition. Letting $u \uparrow t$ yields $$E(\mathbf{1}_A \mathbf{1}(\tau_n \ge t)) = E(\mathbf{1}_A \lim_{u \uparrow t} P(\tau_n > u | \mathcal{F}_u)) \qquad \textbf{(5)}$$ for every $A \in \bigcup_{s<t}\mathcal{F}_s \equiv G$. Since $G$ is a $\pi$-system and sets in $\mathcal{F}_{t-}$ such that (5) hold form a $\lambda$-system, the claim follows by Dynkin's $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem. Now, let $D$ denote the dyadic rationals in $[0, \infty)$. Since $\tau_n \in D$, we have
$$\int_{(0, \infty)} P(\tau_n = t|\mathcal{F}_{t-}) dA_t = \sum_{t \in D} \int_{(0, \infty)}P(\tau_n = s |\mathcal{F}_{s-}) \mathbf{1}(s = t) dA_s = \sum_{t \in D} P(\tau_n = t | \mathcal{F}_{t-}) \Delta A_t = 0$$
since $A$ is continuous at the dyadic rationals. Hence, the right hand side in $(1)$ is actually equal to $$ E\int_{(0, \infty)} P(\tau_n \ge t | \mathcal{F}_{t-}) dA_t = E\int_{(0, \infty)} \lim_{s \uparrow t} P(\tau_n > s | \mathcal{F}_{s}) dA_t$$ by (5) and this quantity converges to $$E \int_{(0, \infty)} \mathbf{1}(\tau \ge t) dA_t$$ by Lemma 10.8, specifically (L10.8) in the question above.
FINALLY, and God-willingly, we are done. I usually love Kallenberg's exposition because he usually strikes the perfect balance (in my opinion) between conciseness and covering the details, but here, these details are woefully lacking (in my opinion of course).
